# geometry node - instance instead of geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes

i have a question...so when i drag a collection into the geometry node editor it appears as instance instead of geometry

like this [image]

i really need help...am i doing something wrong?
im trying to follow a YT tutorial but no matter how many times i redoit it still appears like the first image insted of [image]

Comment: Hi. It looks like Blender changed the node to the one you get between versions 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: It is helpful to know which version you are using vs. the tutorial's version. Especially _Geometry Nodes_ has gone through many, sometimes drastical changes in the beginning. And like @curious_1 said, this node has been changed. I guess the reason is because it was a bit confusing before: the _Object Info_ node provides an object as _Geometry_ (but you can check _As Instance_ if you need it) whereas objects brought in with the _Collection Info_ node were instances (even in earlier versions before the node output was changed to show that) that had to be realized if you needed the geometry.